# MySQL 8.0 permissions issue VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have been doing an update to a purchase app that I developed some time ago.  One of the changes I've been doing is to replace the hard coded queries inside the program with MySQL functions.

The MySQL server is version 8.0 and its running in Ubuntu 18.04 server.  I am aware there are a lot of bugs specially with permissions still going around in the Linux version of MySQL.

The problem I am facing now is that I can run the functions on MySQL Workbench but when trying to execute the function from VB.NET I always get a user permission error.  I already give the user the permission just to execute those functions and I am using the same user in the app than in MySQL Workbench.

Does any one know a solution for this, or there is a special permission that I need to assign in order to execute functions from any other application besides MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Since we don't know what code you used, what error you're getting, or what users / permissions you've got set up, it's pretty much impossible to advise you. But as a general principle, no, MySQL Workbench is no different to any other application which connects to MySQL as a client - there are no special extra permissions required for that, or for any other application. I can only guess that your VB.NET application possibly connects as a different user, which doesn't have permission to run the function. Like I said, if you share some specific details we might be able to diagnose the exact issue

Comment: "I am aware there are a lot of bugs specially with permissions still going around in the Linux version of MySQL" ...such as? Please be specific and provide references for any bugs you are talking about, and how/why you think they may be relevant to your issue.

Comment: (P.S. I don't have enough information to be sure about your problem, but here is a question: Do MySQL Workbench and your VB.NET application run on the same machine as each other, or on different machines? Because as you are hopefully aware, MySQL treats a login from a different machine as a different user with its own set of permissions. So for example `user1` logging in from `machine1` is `user@machine1`, and then `user1` logging in from `machine2` is `user@machine2`. As far as MySQL is concerned, these are two separate users. Just a guess, but maybe this is related to your problem?)

Comment: Yes, same user, same computer.  Its a permit issue because if i give all rights to that user I can run it from VB.net without any problems.  Ill try migrating the database to a Windows Version.

Comment: So you need to each permissions one by one until it no longer works. Keep the permissions which caused it to break when removed, and remove all the ones that made no difference. That way you will discover the correct level of permissions for the app. P.S. It's still unclear why you think Linux has anything to do with it

Comment: If you check the MySQL documentation there are still a lot of bugs on the Linux version, queries are not running correctly and you have to manual update tables for even be able to create users using MySQL Workbench.  The grant option is not doing the changes that is supposed to do for the 8.0 version.  I wasn't able to do a migration today but this weekend I'll do it.

Comment: I have got MySQL running on 18.04 right now and have not experienced any of the problems you're describing, but ok, maybe there is something specific which is affecting you. Can you provide a link to the relevant documentation which refers to this? I'd like to know if my install could potentially be affected.